# c's sprintf altering my counter

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on an assignment for CS50 but i have a strange behaviour of a counter variable after running sprintf function:

```
//recover jpg files from memory

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please submit an input file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filename
    char *infile = argv[1];

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // define the buffer as array of BYTEs
    BYTE buffer[512];

    // define the counter of images found
    int counter = 0;

    // declare the array for the filename
    char filename[3];

    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr)>0)
        {

        if (buffer[0] == 0xff &&
            buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
            buffer[2] == 0xff &&
            (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            printf("%c%c%c\n", filename[0],filename[1],filename[2]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the debug50 tool and i saw that after running fprintf variable counter passes from 0 to a big strange number.

Any suggestions on where is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: `filename` is not large enough to hold `%03i.jpg` - it has size 3 and would require size 8. Therefore your `sprintf` call invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: why size 9? it's not 3 characters?

Comment: Your variables are stored in memory in order *inptr, buffer, counter, filename.  So if counter is getting corrupted buffer is probably exceeding the 512 size.

Comment: You're overflowing ‘filename‘ variable.

Comment: "001.jpg" is a lot more than 3 characters

Comment: oh yes stupid me i forgot the .jpg part and also the end of the string, the null value

Comment: Don't bean-count:)  Unless in a RAM -restricted embedded environment,  just go [128] as a minimum for local char arrays and, even then, use code that cannot write out-of-bounds.

Comment: @MartinJames it's not a real production environment, it's an academic excercise, and in theory that's not a correct practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I got the error:

I forgot to consider the right length of 'filename' variable, and when running sprintf i was exceeding the memory allowed for it

Comment: This is an easy mistake to make.  A good habit to get into is to always call `snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%03i.jpg", counter);`.  `snprintf` is a version of `sprintf` that lets you pass in the size of your array, so that `snprintf` can promise not to overflow it.  (Be aware, though, that if `filename` is *not* an array, but rather a pointer to some other character buffer, `sizeof` won't do what you want, and you'll have to pass something else to give `snprintf` the correct size.)